# Tesseract OCR: How can I get text directly from a window handle without first saving a file

Tags: c++, ocr, tesseract

here is what I am ABLE to do:

Use the [CaptureAnImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  function example from msdn in order to save an image from a window handle to my computer, then use tesseract with this code:

```
STRING text_out;
tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
// Initialize tesseract-ocr with English, without specifying tessdata path
if (api->Init(NULL, "eng")) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
    exit(1);
}
Pix *image = pixRead("captureqwsx.bmp");
api->SetImage(image);
api->SetRectangle(830, 95, 85, 25);
text_out = api->GetUTF8Text();
printf("OCR output:\n%s", text_out.string());
```

In order to retrieve the text from the window handle specified. And it works. Problem is: I feel like saving an image to my computer is not only useless, but probably not really good for the performance of my application...

The solution I found is, use SetImage with it's second definition:

```
  void SetImage(const unsigned char* imagedata, int width, int height,
                int bytes_per_pixel, int bytes_per_line);
```

And here is how I hope you guys can help me... I have no idea how to retrieve the image data, bytes per pixel, and bytes per line of a window... I feel like the original CaptureAnImage function should be able to do that easily with just little bit of modifications, but I don't know how and my searches returned nothing good...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CaptureAnImage` has this line

```
DWORD dwBmpSize = ((bmpScreen.bmWidth * bi.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4 * bmpScreen.bmHeight;
```

which contains all the parameters you need.

`bmWidth` and `bmHeight` are the width and height.  The number of bits per pixel is `bi.biBitCount` which is set to 32, then there are 32/8 = 4 bytes per pixel.  The expression multiplied by `bmHeight` is the number of bytes per scan line, but because we know the color depth is 32 bits, it is just `bmWidth * 4`.

Comment: Thank you! That was it ;) By the way... do you have an idea why the pixels in lpbitmap are reversed upside down...?

Comment: @Noob-programmer: Windows bitmaps usually are stored that way.  See if  Tesseract accepts either negative height or negative bytes per scanline to flip it vertically...